# How to scroll the background surface in PyGame?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scroll, pygame, 2d

I am trying to set up scrolling in my pyGame-based random map generator. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to keep the display from "smearing" the background instead of just scrolling across it. I have made a MCV Example just for Stack Overflow that only displays colored squares. It has the same problem.

*How can I make the display scroll without smearing the screen?*

**This is what the map generator displays after I scroll around a bit:**

[image]

**MCV Example:**

```
""" This example just displays colored squares. """

import pygame
import sys


def main():

    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))

    x_pos = 0
    y_pos = 0
    yellow = (255, 255, 0)
    blue = (0, 0, 255)

    # draw pattern of yellow and blue squares
    for y in range(100):
        for x in range(100):

            if (y + x) % 2 == 0:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, yellow, (x_pos, y_pos, 50, 50))
            else:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue, (x_pos, y_pos, 50, 50))

            x_pos += 50

        y_pos += 50
        x_pos = 0

    while True:  # <-- the pyGame loop

        event = pygame.event.poll()
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        # handle window closing
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            break

        # handle scrolling
        if pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
            screen.scroll(0, 2)
        elif pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            screen.scroll(0, -2)
        elif pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            screen.scroll(2, 0)
        elif pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            screen.scroll(-2, 0)

        # updates what the window displays
        pygame.display.update()

    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # runs the pyGame loop
    main()
```

**Initial MCVE image**

[image]

**MCVE Display After Scrolling:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pygame.Surface.scroll()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.scroll) doesn't do what you expect. It doesn't seamless *roll* the surface. See the documentation:

> `scroll()` Shift the surface image in place
>
> [...] Areas of the surface that are not overwritten retain their original pixel values. [...]

You've to write your own *scroll* functions, which place the part of the surface, which was shifted out, at the other side of thee surface.

e.g. write 2 functions (`scrollX` and `scrollY`), which can *roll* along an axis:

```py
def scrollX(screenSurf, offsetX):
    width, height = screenSurf.get_size()
    copySurf = screenSurf.copy()
    screenSurf.blit(copySurf, (offsetX, 0))
    if offsetX < 0:
        screenSurf.blit(copySurf, (width + offsetX, 0), (0, 0, -offsetX, height))
    else:
        screenSurf.blit(copySurf, (0, 0), (width - offsetX, 0, offsetX, height))
```

```py
def scrollY(screenSurf, offsetY):
    width, height = screenSurf.get_size()
    copySurf = screenSurf.copy()
    screenSurf.blit(copySurf, (0, offsetY))
    if offsetY < 0:
        screenSurf.blit(copySurf, (0, height + offsetY), (0, 0, width, -offsetY))
    else:
        screenSurf.blit(copySurf, (0, 0), (0, height - offsetY, width, offsetY))
```

```py
if pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
    scrollY(screen, 2)
elif pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
    scrollY(screen, -2)
elif pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    scrollX(screen, 2)
elif pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    scrollX(screen, -2)
```

[image]