# Having trouble keeping the map picture on the pygame screen

Tags: python, pygame

I am having a bit of trouble being able to align the map picture on the pygame window. I want to have it so the map picture will always fill the whole screen. I have already made it so that the map picture moves when the player moves but it is unable to show the whole map.

(These are not the images i will use in my actual game just using them to test)
[Here is what happens if you move to the maximum up and left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SClC0.png)
[image]

[When the character moves to the maximum down and right. Some of the image is still cut off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaSPE.png) 
[image]

Here is my code that i am using:

```
import pygame 
from pygame.locals import *
from math import sin

pygame.display.set_caption("TEST")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
time_passed = 0
class Player():
  def __init__(self,x,y):
    self.Image = pygame.image.load("myAvatar.png").convert()

    self.x = 200
   
    self.y = 200
  

  def getX(self):
    return self.rect.x

  def getY(self):
    return self.rect.y

  def handle_keys(self,screenHeight,screenWidth):
      key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
      dist = 2 

      if key[K_LEFT] and self.x > 0: 
            self.x -= 500 * time_passed
      
      if key[K_RIGHT] and self.x < screenWidth -20:
            self.x += 500 * time_passed
         
      if key[K_UP] and self.y > 0:
        self.y -= 500 * time_passed
      
      if key[K_DOWN] and self.y < screenHeight -20:
        self.y += 500 * time_passed
  


  def draw(self, game_window):
    self.Image = pygame.transform.scale(self.Image,(20,20))
    
    game_window.blit(self.Image, (int(self.x), int(self.y)))


class Map():
  def __init__(self):
    self.Image = pygame.image.load("testbackground.jpg").convert()




    self.rect = self.Image.get_rect()
    self.x = 0
    self.y = 0


  def draw(self, game_window,screenHeight,screenWidth):
    self.Image = pygame.transform.scale(self.Image,(800,800))
    self.x = min(max(self.x, player.x - 2  * screenWidth / 3), player.x - screenWidth / 3)
    self.y = min(max(self.y, player.y -2  * screenHeight / 3), player.y - screenHeight / 3)
      


    game_window.blit(self.Image,(-self.x,-self.y))
 


class Enemy():
  def __init__ (self,x,y):
    self.Image = pygame.image.load("WC.jpg").convert()


    self.rect  = self.Image.get_rect(topleft = (x,y))


  
  def draw(self, game_window):
    self.Image = pygame.transform.scale(self.Image,(20,20))
    game_window.blit(self.Image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))




pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screenWidth = 400
screenHeight = 400
game_window = pygame.display.set_mode((screenWidth,screenHeight))
player = Player(200,200)
map = Map()
enemy = Enemy(250,250)
leave = False
while not leave:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      pygame.quit() 
      running = False



  player.handle_keys(screenHeight,screenWidth)

  game_window.fill((0,0,0))
  map.draw(game_window,screenHeight,screenWidth)
  #enemy.draw(game_window)
  player.draw(game_window)
 
  pygame.display.update()
  pygame.display.flip()
  time_passed = clock.tick() / 1000


pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `blit` the background multiple times. See [How to scroll the background surface in PyGame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55319181/how-to-scroll-the-background-surface-in-pygame/55321731#55321731).
If the background is moved along the x and y axes, 4 background "tiles2 must be put on the screen:

```py
class Map():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Image = pygame.image.load("testbackground.jpg").convert()
        self.Image = pygame.transform.scale(self.Image, game_window.get_size())
                
        self.rect = self.Image.get_rect()
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0


    def draw(self, game_window,screenHeight,screenWidth):
        
        self.x = player.x - screenWidth // 2
        self.y = player.y - screenHeight // 2
        
        x1 = self.x % self.Image.get_width()
        x2 = x1 - self.Image.get_width()
        y1 = self.y % self.Image.get_height()
        y2 = y1 - self.Image.get_height()
        
        game_window.blit(self.Image, (x1, y1))
        game_window.blit(self.Image, (x2, y1))
        game_window.blit(self.Image, (x1, y2))
        game_window.blit(self.Image, (x2, y2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I want to keep the player on one single image instead of duplicating it like that. I am just having trouble realigning the position of the image. Have you got any fix for that?