# How to resize pygame window indefinitely

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have some code like shown below:

```py
import pygame
import random
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

def xor(a, b):
    #input: two byearrays
    #output: bytearray of their xor
    if len(a) > len(b):
        temp = a
        a = b
        b = temp
    s = []
    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        s.append(a[i] ^ b[i])
    for i in range(len(a), len(b)):
        s.append(b[i])
    return s

def cribpend(a, crib, loc):
    #crib is too small; append it with 0's depending on location
    s = []
    for i in range(0, loc):
        s.append(0)
    for i in range(0, len(crib)):
        s.append(crib[i])
    for i in range(len(crib) + loc, len(a)):
        s.append(0)
    s = s[:len(a)]
    return s

def bit(a):
    #returns bitstring of integer
    s = ""
    while (a != 0):
        if (a % 2 == 0):
            s += "0"
            a /= 2
        else:
            s += "1"
            a -= 1
            a /= 2
    while len(s) < 8:
        s += "0"
    s = s[::-1]
    return s

def s_to_ints(s):
    #convert string to integer list ("bytearray")
    b = []
    for i in range(0, len(s)):
        b.append(ord(s[i]))
    return b
    

def showbytes(a, crib=0):
    s = ""
    chars = []
    for i in range(65, 91):
        chars.append(i)
    for i in range(97, 123):
        chars.append(i)
    for i in range(44, 47):
        chars.append(i)
    #return string of bytestring
    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        if (a[i] in chars):
            s += chr(a[i])
        elif (a[i] == 0):
            if (crib == 0):
                s += "█"
            if (crib == 1):
                s += " "
        elif (a[i] == 32):
            s += " "
        else:
            s += "*"
    return s



is_blue = 1
done = 0
x = 30
y = 30
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

p1s = "b'\x85\x8d\xe7\xc0VF@\xb2\xaeP`\xf5j\xf2\xd8i\x8e\xa4\x95J\x0ba\x00\xab\xd5\xcb\xca\rY\x9e\xb4Z\xc0\t6\x99qh[\xf1\xb0\xb2p\x81\xae\x02\xad\xd6\x94\"+\xa2\xa1\x03R\xd3\xa1\x0e\xe9\x1a\x06\xd4l\xca\xc6q\xd1\xa3\x88\xff_\xb6\x03qk\xb5lm\xab\xe2r\xdd\x95p\xbc\x0f\x0f\xe1\xe84\xae\x18\x18\xea\x12\xfe\xe3\xb2\xc0\xbb\xde\r\xdb*\xf3\xd3\x88v\xc9}\x1am\xe9\x01\xff\x89N\x07\xd8\x1e\xcd\x85\xaa\x91!P\x87\xa2I\x91E\x85\x9c\xc0\xf5cV\xaf\x0fTZjo0:\xf3BGq\xca7L\xe8\xd0\xe3{\xcf}b\xc4\xc2\xf9\xa4\xbfn\x1d\\`\x9f\xcd\xe7\xf9\xd8\x99\x86\xb5m\xf9G\xb6,\xddt\xa9~\x9b>i\xb3rs\xa6\xbd\x8b\xf8\xde$=\xe2A\x953C\xfe\xd8\x06w\xe47\x91\x0bF\xee\xbb\x92\xe3\x04\xac^\xaf\x01\x9e\xcd\n\x84\xb5Jv@>\x0b\xc8\xbd\xc5f\xe75\xe7B\xc3\xae\x9e\x12\x92\xdd\x8fb\x1c\x98.&\x8e\xd1\xfb?s\xf6\x92!\x01N\x8d\xe8\xe9Qk\xf8.\x8dQ\xc1j\x08sZ\x02#\xad\xc0\x97\xfd=Y\xdf\x1bUy\x0bfj8c\xde\x1bd\xcc\xf8r\x84\xcc\x1c\x0e/\'^[\xb6\x7fL\xf0\x0e~\x7f\xb4\x96\xc7UQ\x05j\\st~F\x8e\xb4rB\xc6\x17\xf9\xd8\xff6V&$r\xbf\xf7%\xbe:\xb4\xb8\xe7\xff\xecn\x07\x17A\xf2\x844\x8c\x9f\xbf\xa5!&\xfa\xac\xd5s\xe3\x17\xb25\xdcR\xbak \xba\x01:\x9d=<4V\xf3\xf54\x03h\xb0M\x04\x90\xb2tu\x9a\xf0\x89\xce1\xb4?\x8f\x19\xe1\xa8Fr]\xe7\x1d\x01\xd5\xb5f\xf1?y\xa0\xfb]\x95%\xfeN.?\x87\x9b\xbe \xa8\xbb\xd2\n\x1b\xcc\x0b\xbe\xdf\x12\x1d\xcf\xca\x1b\xfc\x97\x99-5\xa1\x80\xc8r\rPE\xf7\x92\xcc\x8a\x05r\xd8\xb4\xbb\xecu\xa9\xe3o\x8e\xbe\xc6\xbc\xaa\x83\x88N\xa0\xf0Q\xbfTz\x9a\xe4\x9a\xf2\xaaUc\x95\xb0i\x92\xf9\x1ac\x0b\xb8\xbf\x12\x88\x06\xcew\xb3{Pn\x85\xea\xec\xc1\xe0\xf2Q\xde\xa46\xc2\xa4d\xe8\xac\x19\x82\x8am\xab\x80\xf0\xf1\x93\x8f\xdbX\xdes!}\x8fA.\xa5\xc5\x9a8\x9b\xees\xfa-\xfdiej\xd6\x83\xb5\x95\xf8\x8d\x8f\xba\xd3-\xd4e\xdd\xfb\xa1\xa7u\x04\xb1\x8f\x08\xdb\x95\xafl \xab)N\xd3\xb5>\xb6T\x14sK}\x01\xc1=\xa4'"
p2s = "b'\x98\x8b\xa2\x94\\Q\x0f\xf7\xff\x00\"\xf5f\xba\xd8~\x8e\xb2\xd4]\x10q\n\xec\x81\xd3\x85\x01N\x9f\xfd_\x94H,\x884+G\xe8\xa1\xb5p\xc4\xb3I\xea\xdb\x9f5y\xb1\xb0\x0fQ\x9d\xe8H\xca\x13\x0c\xda~\x88\xc5j\xcb\xa3\x8b\xf6I\xb6\n{u\xaf{|\xbc\xa63\xd2\x82p\xb2[\x00\xe8\xfby\xb1\x0b\x05\xeb\x12\xfe\xae\xb2\x81\xa6\xc4\x11\x8f8\xfa\xc4\xc1B\xcf8\x1em\xaf\x0f\xac\xbcI\n\x9d\x1b\x84\x85\xaa\xd4qV\x94\xa0H\x95G\xc4\x9f\x86\xb0qX\xafLsL% -1\xf3a@f\xdfs\x0f\xcd\xd4\xf0#\x8ap6\x85\xdb\xb8\xb6\xf1fPI}\x80\xc7\xa9\xff\xdd\x99\x9a\xb5=\xec\x07\xf74\xddp\xa4i\xd2!l\xe1i5\xe9\xab\xd9\xe3\xd13x\xd5W\xd8=J\xf5\x8a\x00{\xe2p\xd45L\xf4\xbb\x8a\xf2V\xe8\x1b\xa9\x08\x97\x89\x10\x83\xaaGz\x0fr\x11\xc5\xea\x83J\xe71\xf4M\xc6\xeb\x9e\x13\x9e\xd6\x8fo\x1e\x9bx(\xda\xf5\xf1 7\xba\xba9\x01P\x81\xa6\xfePg\xf0)\x8a\x1e\x80y\x07gGC8\xb1\xdb\xd9\xbc:S\xdf^\t?Hfn\"c\xc9Oe\xca\xeb>\xd7\xd9\x1f\r),O[\xb6~J\xe2\x13:|\xbf\xc4\x8bOU\r/\x08t}-W\xc6\xbe4\x11\xcfX\xaf\xdb\xa3\x7fe)(x\xf7\xa03\xb3&\xfb\xa0\xe2\xec\xed<\n\x15\x0c\xec\x81#\xc0\x9b\xf1\xe261\xfb\xb0\xd4>\xe9\x1d\xeb`\xddZ\xa6i \xba\x1c=\x9a -(F\xea\xbepjv\xe2V\x1c\x86\xb2qz\x8d\xf9\xdc\x9ba\xech\xdcZ\xaf\xac\x12`W\xf8M\x01\xce\xf02\xf3pg\xbc\xfdL\x95d\xf0\x06*q\x8f\x82\xa97\xa8\xa2\xd5\x0b\x07\x9e\x06\xf1\xc3\x13\x18\x84\x8fY\xe6\x85\x99?2\xb6\x80\xcai\x0bTE\xb4\x89\xdd\xc5\x06d\x86\xf1\xe8\xf4w\xa5\xa6.\x94\xf0\x91\xa0\xa7\x88\x88N\xad\xf9\x14\xa4Rg\x80\xff\x91\xa0\xeeXu\x92\xaex\x8f\xad\x0fy\x00\xf7\x98\x1a\x99G\xc3w\x82{Qk\xc5\xb3\xb8\xc8\xeb\xefQ\xd3\xadb\xd3\xa5(\xf9\xb5P\x84\x90f\xec\xc4\xc9\xe4\x93\x95\xd9Q\xdeU/z\x98N?\xa5\xcc\xc9H\x9d\xf3q\xb2.\xfbouj\xc7\x92\xfc\x9b\xe5\x8d\xb0\xa6\x9a7\xdfe\xdd\xf2\xae\xf5Q\x11\xfd\x99\x1e\x94\xc6\x88gr\xfc?\\\x81\xb2#\xb4F\x1d6[}\x13\x84%\xa3'"

#our byte arrays are just integer lists
p1 = s_to_ints(p1s)
p2 = s_to_ints(p2s)
#generate
k = []
for i in range(0, len(p1s)):
    k.append(random.randint(0, 255))

c1 = xor(p1, k)
c2 = xor(p2, k)

x = xor(c1, c2)
#print(showbytes(p1))
#print(showbytes(p2))
##print showbytes(c1)
##print showbytes(c2)
##print showbytes(x)


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 1000), pygame.RESIZABLE)
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))





r = []
is_cap = 0
is_drag = 0
inputting = 0
loc = 0
towrite = 0
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if (event.pos[0] >= 100 and event.pos[1] >= 390 and event.pos[1] <= 435):
                is_drag = 1
                #start dragging
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION and is_drag == 1:
            loc = (event.pos[0] - 100) / 15
            if (loc < 0):
                loc = 0
            if (loc > 500):
                loc = 500
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            is_drag = 0
            if (event.pos[0] >= 100 and event.pos[1] >= 390 and event.pos[1] <= 435):
                #override the rest; we don't want to change output
                continue
            charnum = (event.pos[0] - 100)/15
            lineremain = event.pos[1] % 100
            linenum = int((event.pos[1] - 90) / 100)
            charnum = int(charnum)
            if (charnum >= 0 and charnum <= 500):
                towrite = 1
            else:
                towrite = 0
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and inputting == 1:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE or event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                inputting = 0
                continue
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LSHIFT or event.key == pygame.K_RSHIFT:
                is_cap = 1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE and len(r) > 0:
                if (is_cap == 1):
                    r = r[:-5]
                else:
                    r = r[:-1]
            else:
                try:
                    this_r = int(event.key)
                    if (is_cap == 1):
                        this_r = max(0, this_r - 32)
                    r.append(this_r)
                except:
                    pass
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and inputting == 0:
            if (event.key == pygame.K_RETURN):
                inputting = 1
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and inputting == 1:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LSHIFT or event.key == pygame.K_RSHIFT:
                is_cap = 0
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
            # Correct the new window size values according to your limits
            new_width = min(event.w, 100000)
            new_height = min(event.h, 100000)
            # Recreate the screen object with the corrected values
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode((new_width, new_height), pygame.RESIZABLE)
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 22, bold=True)
    label = myfont.render("CMPT403 Crib-dragging demo", 1, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(label, (15, 15))
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 22, italic=True)
    label = myfont.render("Ciphertext 1 (C1):", 1, (0, 125, 0))
    screen.blit(label, (50, 50))
    label = myfont.render("Ciphertext 2 (C2):", 1, (0, 125, 0))
    screen.blit(label, (50, 150))
    label = myfont.render("Xortext (X = C1 XOR C2):", 1, (0, 125, 0))
    screen.blit(label, (50, 250))
    label = myfont.render("Crib (R):", 1, (255, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(label, (50, 350))
    label = myfont.render("Xorcribtext (X XOR R):", 1, (0, 125, 0))
    screen.blit(label, (50, 450))
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 25)
    label = myfont.render(showbytes(c1), 1, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(label, (100, 100))
    label = myfont.render(showbytes(c2), 1, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(label, (100, 200))
    label = myfont.render(showbytes(x), 1, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(label, (100, 300))
    loc = int(loc)
    rp = cribpend(c1, r, loc) #r, appended
    label = myfont.render(showbytes(rp, crib=1), 1, (255, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(label, (100, 400))
    xr = xor(x, rp)
    label = myfont.render(showbytes(xr), 1, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(label, (100, 500))
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 10)
    for j in range(0, 5):
        tx = 100
        ty = 100
        width = 100000
        height = 100
        pygame.draw.polygon(screen, (0, 235, 235),
                            ((tx, ty+j*100), (tx+width, ty+j*100),
                             (tx+width, ty+height+j*100), (tx, ty+height+j*100)),
                            2)
    if (inputting == 1):
        j = 3
        pygame.draw.polygon(screen, (255, 0, 0),
                            ((tx, ty+j*100), (tx+width, ty+j*100),
                             (tx+width, ty+height+j*100), (tx, ty+height+j*100)),
                            2)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 0, 0),
                         (100+(loc+len(r))*400, 400), (100+(loc+len(r))*15, 425)
                         )
    for j in range(0, 5):
        for i in range(0, 500):
            label = myfont.render("  " + str(i) + "  ", 5, (150, 150, 150))
            screen.blit(label, (100 + i * 15 + 4, 80 + j * 100))
    if (towrite == 1):
        vnames = ["C1", "C2", "Xortext", "R", "Xorcribtext"]
        vname = vnames[linenum]
        vs = [c1, c2, x, rp, xr]
        vstr = str(vs[linenum][charnum])
        vstr += str(" (" + bit(vs[linenum][charnum]) + ")")
        myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 18)
        label = myfont.render("Char " + str(charnum) + " of " + vname + ": " + vstr, 1, (0, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(label, (100, 600))
        if linenum == 2:
            s = "C1[{}] XOR C2[{}] = {}({}) XOR {}({}) = {}({})".format(
                charnum, charnum,
                c1[charnum], bit(c1[charnum]),
                c2[charnum], bit(c2[charnum]),
                x[charnum], bit(x[charnum]))
            label = myfont.render(s, 1, (135, 0, 0))
            screen.blit(label, (100, 630))
        if linenum == 4:
            s = "X[{}] XOR R[{}] = {}({}) XOR {}({}) = {}({})".format(
                charnum, charnum,
                x[charnum], bit(x[charnum]),
                rp[charnum], bit(rp[charnum]),
                xr[charnum], bit(xr[charnum]))
            label = myfont.render(s, 1, (135, 0, 0))
            screen.blit(label, (100, 630))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)
```

I declared pygame as resizable, however it only allows me to resize the window up to the first 106 characters, and then it will not allow me to resize the window any further, I have 500 characters, how would I resize it so all 500 characters can be seen? I want to be able to stay at the same zoom level and just be able to drag the window to resize it.

Comment: The maximum size of a window is system-dependent and not infinite. So you cannot resize a Pygame window indefinitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum size of a window is system-dependent and not infinite. So you cannot resize a Pygame window indefinitely. SDL provides [`SDL_GetWindowMaximumSize`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_GetWindowMaximumSize)  method to get the maximum size of a window (Pygame uses SDL under the hood).
However, resizing a window beyond the limits of the screen should not be the solution. Growing a window larger than you can see on the screen is pointless and only wastes memory and performance and ends up being very laggy. The solution should be to use a maximized or full-size window and draw only the area of the scene in the window that should be displayed. Therefore, you need to make the window scrollable like that [How to scroll the background surface in PyGame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55319181/how-to-scroll-the-background-surface-in-pygame/55321731#55321731).